# How to use Google sheet API V4 insert note in cell by python

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I don't know how to add note in a cell by Google Sheet API:
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values#writing_multiple_ranges

I read info of Google Sheet API:  https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#CellData

I also read this question but it's still not working
[Is it possible to use the Google Spreadsheet API to add a comment in a cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12913874/is-it-possible-to-use-the-google-spreadsheet-api-to-add-a-comment-in-a-cell)

I don't know how to set note in the value.
I need someone help ~! 
Thanks a lot.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import httplib2
import os

from apiclient import discovery
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import tools
from oauth2client.file import Storage

try:
    import argparse
    flags = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[tools.argparser]).parse_args()
except ImportError:
    flags = None

# If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
# at ~/.credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-python-quickstart.json
# Scope type --> https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'  
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'client_secret.json'        # credentials file name
APPLICATION_NAME = 'auto_update_caspar'


def get_credentials():
"""Gets valid user credentials from storage.

If nothing has been stored, or if the stored credentials are invalid,
the OAuth2 flow is completed to obtain the new credentials.

Returns:
    Credentials, the obtained credential.
"""
home_dir = os.path.expanduser('~')
credential_dir = os.path.join(home_dir, '.credentials')
if not os.path.exists(credential_dir):
    os.makedirs(credential_dir)
credential_path = os.path.join(credential_dir,
                               'auto_update_client_caspar.json')

store = Storage(credential_path)
credentials = store.get()
if not credentials or credentials.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
    flow.user_agent = APPLICATION_NAME
    if flags:
        credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags)
    else: # Needed only for compatibility with Python 2.6
        credentials = tools.run(flow, store)
    print('Storing credentials to ' + credential_path)
return credentials

def main():
"""Shows basic usage of the Sheets API.

Creates a Sheets API service object and prints the names and majors of
students in a sample spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1k7OmDU_QUrCPVmsEpWFRCj-4BOu6PcUb7-SQlA7T_8I/edit
"""
credentials = get_credentials()
http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
discoveryUrl = ('https://sheets.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?'
                'version=v4')
service = discovery.build('sheets', 'v4', http=http,
                          discoveryServiceUrl=discoveryUrl)

spreadsheetId = '1lEJeSNe5T3rNXEEMjY4D04QkoW-ngOeiFo40_S4H4FI'
rangeName = 'stress_temp!A3'

result = service.spreadsheets().values().get(
    spreadsheetId=spreadsheetId, range=rangeName).execute()
print (result)
values = result.get('values', [])

if not values:
    print('No data found.')
else:
    print('Name, Major:')
    for row in values:
        # Print columns A and E, which correspond to indices 0 and 4.
        print('%s' % row[0])



value_input_option = 'RAW'
range_name = 'stress_temp!A3'
values = [['aa']]
data = [
    {
        'range': range_name,
        'values': values
    },
]`enter code here`
body = {
  'valueInputOption': value_input_option,
  'data': data
}
result = service.spreadsheets().values().batchUpdate(
    spreadsheetId=spreadsheetId, body=body).execute()



if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

Answer (score 2):

In Python, I use this piece of code and it work.

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.oauth2 import service_account

SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file",
                  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"]
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'credentials.json'

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=credentials)

spreadsheetId = "O188999ITC"
sheetid_src = "123a"
notes = {
            "updateCells": {
                "range": {
                    "sheetId": sheetid_src,
                    "startRowIndex": 1,
                    "endRowIndex: 1,
                    "startColumnIndex": 1,
                    "endColumnIndex": 1
                },
                "rows": [
                    {
                        "values": [
                            {
                                "note": "my note"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "fields": "note"
            }
        }
body = {"requests":[notes]}
result = service.spreadsheets().values().batchUpdate(
    spreadsheetId=spreadsheetId, body=body).execute()
```

Note are available in API with cellData, so you have to update values of differents cells with the keyword "Notes".

You can find more information here :
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/cells#celldata

Comment: this should be `result = service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(
    spreadsheetId=spreadsheetId, body=body).execute()` without the `values()`. didn't work for me with it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any documentation regarding your issue. You may refer with this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32359481/how-to-get-a-note-or-comment) however it discussed how to get a note using `getNote()`. In your case, you need to use Google Apps Script and use the methods:

- [`setNote(note)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setnotenote) - Sets the note to the given value.
- [`setNotes(notes)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setnotesnotes) - Sets a rectangular grid of notes (must match dimensions of this range).

You may also check into this [related reported issue](https://github.com/burnash/gspread/issues/50). Hope this helps!